# 'One-lineize' python statement

Tags: python

I'd like to know if one can write the following statement in one line:

```
new = ''
for char in text:
    if char in blacklist:
        new += ' '
    else:
        new += char
```

I tried but I get syntax error:

```
new = ''.join(c for c in text if c not in blacklist else ' ')
```

I know is not better or prettier, I just want to know if it's possible.

Comment: Elegant solutions or expressions are also called "idiomatic" (sounds better than "one-linized")

Comment: @Otto: But he wasn't asking for the most elegant. He was specifically asking for a one-liner, even with the *explicit* understanding that it might not be "better or prettier". Which shows pretty decent instincts, because *idiomatic* Python *is* supposed to be as readable as possible. In this case, I do think the one-liner he was going for happens to be quite readable to experienced Python programmers, so it is both a one-liner *and* idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using your in-line conditional in the wrong place (it'd work if you didn't have the `else ' '` there, as then it'd just be a filter on the iterable). As it is, you'll want to do it this way:

```
new = ''.join(c if c not in blacklist else ' ' for c in text)
```

You could also do it like this if you wanted:

```
new = ''.join(' ' if c in blacklist else c for c in text)
```

Answer (score 3):

Iterating over it seems like an overly complicated way to do it. Why not use a [regex](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)?

```
import re
blacklist = re.compile(r'[xyz]') # Blacklist the characters 'x', 'y', 'z'
new = re.sub(blacklist, ' ', text)
```

Comment: I know with regex it's easier, It's just a concrete example without regular expressions

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it:

```
''.join(c if c not in blacklist else ' ' for c in text)
```

The `X if Y else Z` is an expression in itself, so you can't split it up by putting the `for c in text` part in the middle.

Comment: Hard to choose between JAB's answer and this one, as they are almost exactly the same (or they were, before JAB's edit).  I like this one slightly better because it contains a bit of explanation of the if..else ternary expression.  Also a tiny bit of bonus on this one for the encouraging tone ("almost had it").  Not that JAB's answer was bad in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the translate method of str. Build a string of your whitelist characters, with ' ' in place of the blacklist ones:

```
>>> table = ''.join(c if c not in 'axy' else ' ' for c in map(chr,range(256)))
```

Then call translate with this table:

```
>>> 'xyzzy'.translate(table)
'  zz '
```

Comment: That seems just a bit overkill.